# Creating a date range fields with pikaday datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, pikaday

I'm trying to use the pikaday datepicker, I'm trying to avoid jquery datepicker because of its dependancies and heavy images, but I can't achieve what I want with pikaday.

I have a from to field in a form, The date that can be selected in the to field shouldn't be past to the from field.. I tried like below but it is not working.

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('start')
});
var picker2 = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('end'),
    minDate: new Date(document.getElementById('start').value)
});
```

A Pure javascript solution is better for me, 
Anyone can guide me in this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the methods `setMinDate` and `setMaxDate` when a new date is selected by the [pickaday control](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday#get-and-set-date):

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('start'),
    onSelect: function() {
        picker2.setMinDate(this.getDate());
    }
});
var picker2 = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('end'),
    onSelect: function() {
        picker.setMaxDate(this.getDate());
    }
});
```

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uHKh6/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I came near to this but I don't know this methods of pikaday like `picker2.setMinDate`, Where did you read about this method..?

Comment: @vignesh_ms I'm glad it helped :) Just click the link in the answer. It links you to the github page.

Comment: after too much googling, i came up to this answer and realize I should have read documentation nicely :D. Thanks @A1rPun

Answer (score 6):

I extended @A1Prun's answer to match my exact requirmentes, Here is the updated answer, Hope it'll help someone.

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('start'),
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function() {
        picker2.setMinDate(new Date(this.getDate().getTime()+parseInt(24*60*60*1000)));
        if(Number(new Date(this.getDate()))>Number(new Date(document.getElementById('end').value)))
        {
            document.getElementById('end').value="";
        }
    }
});
var picker2 = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('end'),
});
```